# Stacked bar chart with percentage

Tags: sas

Using Sas 9.3 I'm trying to do a stacked bar chart basing on some crosstab. I know, how to do it with 9.4, but in 9.3 it looks much more difficult to me.

Let's say a I have such a crosstab (in wide form):

```
group    v1_0    v1_1
  A       12       88
  B       17       83
  C       29       71
```

As you can see - rows sum up to 100.

Alternatively, I can have it in a long form:

```
group    v1    val
  A      0      12
  A      1      88
  B      0      17
  B      1      83
  C      0      29
  C      1      71
```

I tried, among others:

```
proc sgplot data=long_form_data;
    vbar val / groupdisplay=stack group=group response=v1;
run;
```

But It does not produce anything sensible.

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

9.4 code would look probably like this:

```
proc sgplot data=long_form_data pctlevel=group;
    vbar val / groupdisplay=stack group=group response=v1;
run;
```

And same chart made with Excel looks like below:

[image: Example chart]

Comment: Thanks for including the example in 9.4.  Are the display labels important to you?  That's really the only difference in 9.4 vs 9.3.  Though that 9.4 code wouldn't actually run the way you want it to I don't think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vbar`'s first argument is the category, not the value.  So you have this sort of backwards.

This really isn't different from 9.3 to 9.4, although 9.4 has some better options for labelling the bars.

```
data have;
  input group    $ v1    val;
datalines;
  A      0      12
  A      1      88
  B      0      17
  B      1      83
  C      0      29
  C      1      71
;;;;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
  vbar group/response=val group=v1 groupdisplay=stack;
run;
```

There are other ways to do this also; you can read my paper [Labelling without the hassle](http://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2014/DV/MWSUG-2014-DV04.pdf) for some of those other methods, including using GTL.

If the bar labels are important to you, well, read my paper above - that's what it's about.  The simplest way to do it us using high-low bars and a scatterplot.  (You can't overlay scatterplots on VBARs, unfortunately, and VBARPARM didn't allow stacked for some reason in 9.3.)

```
*Create a dataset with yMin and yMax being bottom/top of each bar segment;
*yScatter is the midpoint of each bar segment, location to put the label;
data have_highlow;
  set have;
  by group v1;
  if first.group then _yBase=0;  
  yMin = _yBase;
  yMax = val + _yBase;
  yScatter = (val/2) + _yBase;
  output;
  _ybase+val;
run;

proc SGPLOT data=have_highlow;
 *Here is the bar chart (which is a highlow chart plotting each segment);
 highlow x=group low=yMin high=yMax/
    type=bar barwidth=0.6 group=v1
    groupdisplay=overlay;

 *Need to use discreteoffset to center the label (this is a bit messy);
 scatter x=group y=yScatter/ discreteoffset=-0.08
    markerchar=val markercharattrs=
 (size=18pt color=white);

run;
```